# Excel VBA Code to check if a stored procedure exists on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am writing an Excel VBA macro that calls a SQL stored procedure. I would like to write code in VBA that tests whether or not that stored procedure exists. I have code as follows:

```
Public Function Import_StoredProcedure_Results(usp As ADODB.Command, _
                        ExecRun_UID As String, _
                        Scenario As Integer, _
                        OutputSheet As String, _
                        uspSPName As String) As Boolean

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Import_StoredProcedure_Results = False

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    With usp
        .Parameters("@ID").Value = "{" & Run_UID & "}"
        .Parameters("@RunType").Value = RunType

        Set rs = .Execute
    End With
    'Write results to Output sheet
    If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        i = 0
        'Copy in the header row
        For Each fld In rs.Fields
            Sheets(OutputSheet).Range("A1").Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, i).Value = fld.Name
            i = i + 1
        Next fld
        'Copy in the data
        Sheets(OutputSheet).Range("A1").Cells(1, 1).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
    End If
    Import_StoredProcedure_Results = True
    rs.Close
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description & " " & "Error - Import_StoredProcedure_Results: " & uspSPName
End Function
```

The code goes to the Error Handler when it tries to execute the line

```
.Parameters("@ID").Value = "{" & Run_UID & "}"
```

An error message is then passed back from SQL to say that the given stored procedure does not exist. I would like to discover whether or not this stored procedure exists *before* calling this VBA function. This is so that it will be more modular. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `information_schema.routines` system view holds a list of all stored procedures and functions in your database, as well as meta-data about them. ([learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/routines-transact-sql))

You could run the following query, if you get a result a stored procedure exists with the same name.

```
select count(*) 
from DatabaseName.information_schema.routines 
where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE' and routine_name= 'YourProcedureName'
```

Comment: Thanks JeffUK. What's the best way to pass that through from Excel VBA?